# Javascript - How to change a new value on drop down

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

When we change the `name="quantity"` and the `$product['price']` value will changing too.  Here will have dynamic quantity and price. How to do that using jquery/javascript.

```
<?php
$select  = "SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10"; 
$query  = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<ul>
  <?php while($product = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
  <li>
    <p><?php echo $product['name'];?></p>
    <p> Quantity
      <select name="quantity">
        <?php  for($i=1;$i<=$product['quantity'];$i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
   </p>
   <p><?php echo $product['price'];?></p>
 </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quantity_select").bind("change", function() {
        selected_option = $("option:selected").val();
        $("#counter").html(selected_option);
    });
});
```

...

```
<select id="quantity_select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<div id="counter"></div>
```

You can use `text()` instead of `val()` if you want to see actual text instead of `value` attribute .

Comment: It is bad practice to use JavaScript attributes embedded directly into HTMl.